# PlexMediaServer Not running

Tags: services, nfs

I had PlexMediaServer (PMS from here on) installed on my Ubuntu Machine,

recently i switched from sshfs to NFS for my network shares,

PMS managed to stream perfectly from my network shares when i was on sshfs, but it stopped working as i enabled and used NFS. (Mind you library updates still happened successfully)

I thought it was a PMS issue so i thought lets remove it completely and reinstall again,

so i removed PMS and removed the /var/lib/plexmediaserver folder

now i installed PMS again but it won't run

i noticed it is unable to create the /usr/lib/plexmediaserver folder as it doesnt exist

also i can see that i cannot stop the pms server and every time i run it it runs with a diff pid

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo service plexmediaserver stop
[sudo] password for ubuntu: 
stop: Unknown instance: 
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo service plexmediaserver start
plexmediaserver start/running, process 3935
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo service plexmediaserver start
start: Job is already running: plexmediaserver
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo service plexmediaserver start
plexmediaserver start/running, process 4009
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo service plexmediaserver start
plexmediaserver start/running, process 4079
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo service plexmediaserver start
plexmediaserver start/running, process 4149
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo service plexmediaserver start
start: Job is already running: plexmediaserver
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo service plexmediaserver start
plexmediaserver start/running, process 4223
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo service plexmediaserver start
start: Job is already running: plexmediaserver
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo service plexmediaserver start
start: Job is already running: plexmediaserver
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ 
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$
```

EDIT: running Ubuntu 64 bit 12.04 LTS with PMS beta

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered. If you solved it, please post an answer explaining how it was solved (answering your own questions is not merely permitted, but [encouraged when there is no other answer that does the job](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)). If the question no longer applies you may voluntarily delete/close it.

Answer (score 1):

Removing plex user has solved for me.

```
sudo userdel plex
```